# java openmaple connection with eclipse

Tags: java, maple

[test.java simple example for openmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lf04.png)

Hello buddies!

I have tried so many times to connect java to maple using **openmaple** but get below error. please help me, I'm using **Eclipse** as java editor. thanks in advance

```
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jopenmaple in java.library.pathError loading libraries: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jopenmaple in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at test.main(test.java:23)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine.getKernel([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/maplesoft/openmaple/EngineCallBacks;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)J
    at com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine.getKernel(Native Method)
    at com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:23)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to ensure that Eclipse points to `externalcall.jar`, `jopenmaple.dll`, and `Maple.jar`.

First, add

```
C:\Program Files\Maple 15\java\externalcall.jar
C:\Program Files\Maple 15\java\Maple.jar
```

by right-clicking the project (I called mine `OpenMaple`), and going to `Build Path > Add External Archives`.

Second, create a sub-folder of the package called, say, `DLLs`, and copy the following file to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Maple 15\bin.X86_64_WINDOWS\jopenmaple.dll
```

Then, navigate to

```
Properties > Java Build Path > Source > OpenMaple/src > Native library location
```

and add `OpenMaple/DLLs`.